# Missing two dylib, but no Xcode linking errors

Tags: ios, xcode, dylib

I'm updating an old iOS app using Xcode 7.3.  The deployment target is 7.0 and the previous version was built for iOS 8.  There are about a dozen frameworks included (e.g., *Security.framework*) and also **sqlite3.0.dylib** and **libSystem.B.dylib** which appear in red in the Project Navigator because they can't be found.  Indeed, "Open in Finder" gives no result.

However, despite this, the app compiles, and runs *without errors* in the SIM and on a device, even after Clean.  Somehow the SQLite library is being linked, but what magic is at work here?

I think I should just add **libsqlite3.0.tbd** but I'd like to understand what's going on in case I break something under iOS 7 and 8 (why no link errors?).  Need I about **libSystem.B.dylib** -- is it needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sqlite3.0.dylib** and **libSystem.B.dylib** are system libs. Project navigator and dylib search paths are different things. Project navigator as the name says is used to navigate the project so it is more or less a tool for the developer to easy navigate a project. Usually it also shows your linked libs, but they keep a path to those frameworks and the path is no longer valid in your case. On the other hand there is `Framework Search Paths`  which you can find in `Build settings`. There are the paths where the linker searches for the expected libraries. But since your libs are from the system you don't even need to specify a `Framework search path` because paths to system libs are set by default, so for system libs you just have to specify that you want to link them to your project. So you can safely remove those red libs from your project navigator. And as long as it is specified in your settings that you want to use those libs in `Link Binary With Libraries` the whole thing should work.

Comment: That makes sense. The `Link Binary with Libraries` list does not include **libSystem.B.dylib** (or **libSystem.dylib**).  I recall that library had something to do with the SIM, but several years ago.  Does that predate iOS 7 and no longer needed? Also, **Gamekit** is in the Frameworks list but not in `Link Binary With Libraries` -- how should I deal with that?

Comment: I think you are right, you shouldn't need libSystem.B.dylib, I thought you know for sure that you need those libs. If you do not have Gamekit in `Link Binary with Libraries` you could technically remove it, because it is not used in your project. If your project is old you might have some Game kit `#import`s that will give you errors if you do that. Remove them and you should be fine.